# How do I download a video from a webpage using the src tag?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I want to download a game's video off of a its Steam store page. However, when ever I try to do so, I get the "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" error

This is my code:

```
import urllib.request
import bs4 as bs

source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://store.steampowered.com/app/394690/Tower_Unite/')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')


video = soup.find('video',{'class':'highlight_player_item highlight_movie'})
videoLink = video['src']


urllib.request.urlretrieve(videoLink, '-gameVid.mp4')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an attribute selector as follows:

```
videoLink = soup.select_one('[data-webm-source]')['data-webm-source']
```